# What is the motivation behind the criteria for a random variable to be 'subexponential'?

Tags: distributions, random-variable, definition

I found the following [definition](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Emjwain/stat210b/Chap2_TailBounds_Jan22_2015.pdf):

> Definition 2.2. A random variable X with mean $µ = E[X]$ is sub-exponential if there
> are non-negative parameters $(\nu, b)$ such that $E[e^{λ(X−µ)}] ≤ e^{\frac{\nu^2λ^2}2}\quad \forall |λ| < \frac{1}{b}.$

This looks a bit like a MGF, but it is different from the [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy-tailed_distribution#Subexponential_distributions).

The whole idea seems to come from the Markov inequality $P(X\geq t)=\frac{E(X)}t,$ using the monotonically increasing nature of the exponential function to use the MGF of $X,$ resulting in the Chernoff inequality. The question is why? One thought is that we want to end up saying that there is a bound that decays exponentially with some parameter.